# Multiple delete using PHP dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql

Now i can delete Multiple delete using PHP dreamweaver,but not but only one record can delete. is there something code i've been miss?

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['delete']))
    {
        $deleteCb = $_REQUEST['deleteCb'];   
        for($i=0;$i<count($deleteCb);$i++)
        {
            $final_id = $deleteCb[$i];
            $q = "DELETE FROM tb_final WHERE final_id= ".$final_id;
            mysql_query($q);        
        }
        header("location:basic_multiple.php");
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: What? I don't understand

Comment: Are you saying you solved the issue ?

Comment: Never mind, i solved it, just tnx for your concerns :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

you need to change this line of code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="deleteCb" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['final_id']; ?>" />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="deleteCb[]" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['final_id']; ?>" />
```

And that is because unless you do so, the last value of the deletCb checkbox is the only one that would be passed to your form and hence would work only for that record.

Comment: Yeah, I did that while ago, tnx 4 ur answer, and also I removed the: mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); and now it's working! :D

Comment: if this helped you solve the issue, I think accepting it may help future users